# How can I customize the Style of an Listview Item

Tags: android, delphi, listview, styles, firemonkey

I haven't founded a well guide for understand how customize ListView Items at Design Time.
I also noticed that in the projects FireMonkey Desktop Application HD,
it is possiblible select Edit Custom Style.

In projects FireMonkey Mobile Application does not exist the same functionality

Comment: There's a sample distributed with Delphi that shows exactly how to do this; you can find it in the Samples\Object Pascal\Mobile Samples\User Interface\ListView folder. Several of the projects in that folder require you to install packages (also in that folder) first before running them, for the exact reason that visual design in the IDE requires them. See the `readme.txt` file in that folder for details.

Comment: @KenWhite: that's an answer, not a comment

Comment: Thank you,but the examples don't explain how change for example the background colour in the ListView for Mobile Application

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23456877/how-to-change-the-ttabitems-style/#23565545